# Moodle integration with Shopify

Tags: php, integration, shopify-api, moodle-api, lms

I need help with integration of Moodle with Shopify website. If the integration is possible, I'd also like to know if there will be a need to get an external server like AWS for the database/storage of the course materials and users' records or everything can be done within Shopify.
Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few things you can consider:

1. There are free and paid services for integrating Moodle with Shopify.
2. I've tried [Zapier](https://zapier.com/) free plan, you can create free workflows/services.
3. You've to sign in to your Moodle website (if hosted Moodle personal - CPanel) to access Zapier workflows.
4. You can develop a local plugin and install it by visiting Site Administration -> Plugins -> Install plugins and drag-n-drop the local plugin (zip file) into the filepicker-container. You need to have admin access of your Moodle website.
5. There's a plugin called [Moodle plugin skeleton generator](https://moodle.org/plugins/tool_pluginskel) to set up basic code structure. You've to install this tool by navigating same way.
6. Try out [Moodle themes](https://moodle.org/plugins/?q=type:theme) or customize default themes.
7. You can also check with [Edwiser](https://edwiser.org/) WordPress theme for Moodle and it's free to use and integrate.

Hope that'll help, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer Shopify SSO application for Integration with different apps like Moodle, AWS, and more.